# Clean alternative to BS

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

You're reading a report. It's full of excuses and flat out lies from someone who thinks they can pull one over on you. When you go home and complain about it, you might call it complete bull****. I'm trying to keep my story clean, though, so I'm looking for another way to describe it. I've found synonyms, but I'm still looking for something that sounds natural even from a character who's comfortable swearing.

Comment: It's "fabricated", might fit

Comment: I think you misspelled ***our***. Shouldn't it be ***out***?

Comment: [***Falsehood***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/falsehood) or [***fabrication***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fabrication) as suggested above could fit in your context.

Comment: Please specify which thesauruses and dictionaries you've looked up *bullshit* in, what their suggestions were, and why you rejected each of them. (If you haven't looked up the word in any thesaurus or dictionary, please start by looking it up in a thesaurus or dictionary.) Additionally, please specify what you mean by "unclean". *Bullshit* is a perfectly fine English word to use in a story.

Comment: codswallop, horse hockey, bunk (or bunkum), blather, hokum, nonsense, hooey, malarkey. All these (except for nonsense) are rather out of date and sound really weird.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Clean: not vulgar. I'm not satisfied with the synonyms I've seen because I wouldn't expect someone who swears, or even anyone under 70, to say them.

Comment: If you want to sound angry but not profane, you could use the phrase "complete garbage."

Comment: I like the word "balderdash", but Mitch offers several other great suggestions. The trouble with bullshit is it can be taken as aggressive, an attack on the ideas, where balderdash, rubbish, codswallop, etc., are more dismissive without the aggression.

Comment: @Qaz Check out how politicians talk on the record. They routinely use these weird sounding euphemisms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about Baloney?

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/baloney

You could also remove "s***" and just say "bull."  http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bull.

"I can't believe he said that.  What a bunch of bull."